# ANTLR4: How to specify choice of rules which includes Unicode strings?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I need to parse a CSV table which contains conditions, like

```
1,"a==1 AND b==2"
2,"c==3 AND d==4"
```

For those the grammar below works and #validCondition is called in my visitor.

I'd like to implement a error handling in my visitor (using #invalidCondition) to reject conditions with illegal characters like:

```
5,"c==3 AND ä d==4"
6,"c==3 AND . d==4"
```

With the grammar below #invalidCondition is not called in my visitor, instead I receive

```
line 3:12 token recognition error at: 'ä'
line 4:12 token recognition error at: '.'
```

and ANTLR default error recovery took place. For invalid conditions like

```
4,"c==3 AND a d==4"
```

#invalidCondition is called as intended.

How needs the rule to be specified?

```
grammar Table;

table : row+;

row : INT ',' condition NEWLINE;

condition
    :   '"' expr '"'        #validCondition
    |   '"' ~('"')+ '"'     #invalidCondition
    ;

expr
    :   expr op=(AND | OR) expr         #op
    |   ID comp=(EQUAL | NOT_EQUAL) INT #comp
    |   '(' expr ')'                    #parens
;

EQUAL       : '==';
NOT_EQUAL   : '=!';
OR          : 'OR';
AND         : 'AND';


NEWLINE     : '\r\n';

ID          : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
INT         : [0-9]+ ;
WS          : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have Antlr handle Unicode characters, specify the characters/ranges as part of your lexer rules.  See, for example, how the [Antlr4 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr4/LexUnicode.g4) handles Unicode.

Need to change the `ID` rule or add a rule to allow for the possibility of Unicode input characters.

The reason `invalidCondition` works against the input `a d==4` is because the text lex's as `ID ID '==' INT'`, and that is not matched by the `expr` rule.

The input `ä d==4` would be lex'd  as `UNKNOWN ID '==' INT'`. But, the token recognition error reflects the lexer's inability to identify the character - the UNKNOWN non-token is not passed to the parser and therefore the `invalidCondition` subrule will not be matched.

If Unicode is added to `ID` rule, then the existing `invalidCondition` subrule will work as expected.

If, however, the existing grammar rules cover the entire valid input character set, a rule can be added to catch all other input characters, including Unicode.  After all other rules, add:

```
OTHER : . ;
```

This will avoid the Unicode recognition error. It will require that all valid characters, such as the double quote character, be defined as lexer rules, otherwise they will be lex'd as `OTHER` tokens.

Comment: I don't want to allow additional Unicode input characters for ID. I want #invalidCondition to be called if #validCondition cannot be resolved. #invalidCondition is called if I add for example a 'a', but it is not called if adding a '.' or 'ä' etc.